# How to open html link to local file in its default program, NOT browser?

Tags: html, file, hyperlink, local

Basically, I'm creating a webpage filled with images of movie posters that link to video files, as a means of making a more visually-appealing form of my local video library.

I'm using

```
<a href="C:\blah\movie.mkv"><img src="poster.jpg">
```

It works exactly how I want, HOWEVER, it opens the file in the browser rather than opening it in its default program, as I would like. I would like each link to open the file in the program titled "VLC Media Player", as specified in Windows for each of their filetypes.

Let me know how I can do this (in the simplest form--I'm not too smart :P)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you making a local website? You know, in an actual website, you'll need the client to download the actual file. If you're only going to use it locally, it's fine :)

Comment: I'm just using my own Windows computer. The webpage is for personal use only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little you can do to control how a client will handle a resource.

You can use the [`Content-Disposition` HTTP response header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) to state that the resource is an attachment (and thus recommend that it be downloaded instead of opened).

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="movie.mkv"
```

You can't, however, stop browser native support or a plug-in from handling something instead of having it open in a separate application (let alone cause it to be opened in a specific application).

If the browser is configured to open video files internally, then nothing the author of a website can do will make it switch to using a application instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating web pages on your local system for you own use then you may want to consider looking in to a WAMP server setup. This uses php and should allow you to call VLC using the exec command. Would take some learning however.